# How to enable 3D Cube and other effects in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, compiz, desktop-effects

How to enable 3D Cube and other effects in ubuntu?

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 4):

After enabling Compiz (System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Visual Effects)

Install compiz manager to configure eye candy (cube, animations)

```
sudo apt-get install simple-ccsm
```

after that, go to System -> Preferences -> Simple CompizConfig settings manager

Go to the desktop tab and enable desktop cube, have fun

~ Jeffrey V.

Comment: Note that you'll need to have an accelerated graphics driver installed in order to enable this.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably referring to desktop effects with Compiz.

**System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Visual Effects Tab**

You'll come to this screen:

[image]

**Extra** will provide the most eye candy.

Here is the complete list of keyboard shortcuts from [here](http://helpforlinux.blogspot.com/2008/09/complete-list-of-compiz-keyboard.html):

```
Desktop Effect     Keyboard Shortcut

Rotate Cube         Mousewheel on Desktop
Switcher2       Alt + Tab
Shift Switcher3     Super + Tab (2 modes: flip and cover)
Ring Switcher       Super + Tab - overrides Shift Switcher
Expo            Super + E (toggle)
Film Effect         Ctrl + Alt + Down Arrow4
Rotate Cube Manually    Ctrl + Alt + Left Mouse Button
Scale Windows       Alt + Shift + Up Arrow
Show/Clear Desktop  Ctrl + Alt + D (toggle)
Snapping Windows    Move a window across workspaces5
Screenshot      Super + Left Mouse Button
Zoom In/Out         Super + Mousewheel
Transparent Window  Alt + Mousewheel
Resize Window       Alt + F8
Move Window         Alt + F7
Add Helper      Super + P
Widget Layer        F9 (toggle)
Water Effects       Shift + F9 (toggle)
Fire Effects: On    Super + Shift + Left Mouse Button
Fire Effects: Clear     Super + Shift + C
Annotate: Draw      Super + Left Mouse Button
Annotate: Start     Super + 1
Annotate: End       Super + 3
Group: Select Window(s) Super + S
Group: Group Windows    Super + T
Group: Ungroup Windows  Super + U
Group: Flip Windows     Super + Right or Left Arrow

1 Effects have to be enabled to see results.
2 To see the full effect, have multiple windows or programs open.
3 To configure: Go to Advanced Desktop Effects Settings.
4 Use left and right arrow thereafter to move to workspaces.
5 Disables Wobbly Windows.
```

Comment: If you install ccsm like Jeffrey suggested, there will be a custom settings button under the Visual Effects tab.